# What's the best type of potting soil/mix for a Sansevieria (snake plant)?

Tags: soil, potting-soil, snake-plants

I have a *Sansevevieria* (Snake Plant) and I'm looking for the best type of potting soil/mix for it. I checked some sites on google and couldn't understand a thing. Almost everyone has a different opinion on what kind of soil/mix to use for the succulent plant.

In my neighbourhood, no one in any nursery here understands perlite or other things<sup>**1**</sup>, even after showing a picture. So please tell me what I can do to make the best soil for my Snake plant? Please include some pictures as it will also help me in identifying what type of soil you are talking about.

<sup>1. They are not educated.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I don't know what everyone else uses, but mine (10 years old) is growing in perfectly ordinary multi purpose potting compost, the same stuff I use for outdoors plants. It will have a proportion of peat, probably 50%, and the rest will be recycled and well composted (hot composted) garden waste I imagine. I don't add anything to it to alter it in any way, though its true that newer, low peat or no peat multi purpose potting compost tends to contain lumpy bits like stones and bits of uncomposted wood, so I'd remove those before use. For preference, I'd choose John Innes No. 2, which is loam, peat, sand/grit in ratio - more info regarding 'recipes' for John Innes type composts below, but I doubt you'll find the ingredients where you are: [John Innes potting compost](https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?PID=952).